# How to convert parametric form of tangent line to Cartesian equivalent

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I have calculated the tangent line of the following curve $c(t)=(2cost−cos2t,2sint−sin2t$) @ $t=\pi/4$ to be

$l(t)=(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}-1)+ (t- \frac{\pi}{4})(2-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$

How do I convert this to $y-y_{0}=f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}-1)+ \left(t- \frac{\pi}{4}\right)(2-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$$
we get
$$\begin{cases}
x=\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right) \left(t-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+\sqrt{2}\\
y=\sqrt{2} \left(t-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+\sqrt{2}-1\\
\end{cases}
$$
from the second equation we have

$t-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1$

Plug in the first, expand and simplify
$$\sqrt{2} x+\left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) y=6-3 \sqrt{2}$$

in another form
$$y+3=\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right) x$$
edit

look at the image below. The curve and the tangent at $t=\pi/4$

---

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Somehow your answer is different to that given in the book. I have checked with wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%20x%2B%5Cleft%28%5Csqrt%7B2%7D-2%5Cright%29%20y%3D6-3%20%5Csqrt%7B2%7D and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%E2%88%92%281%2Fsqrt%202%20%E2%88%921%29%20%3D%20%28x%E2%88%92%E2%88%9A2%29%2F%28%E2%88%9A2%E2%88%921%29

Comment: @user9106985 $y-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+1=\frac{x-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}$ is not tangent to the curve

Comment: Ok... the 2nd link I gave you is the answer I see in the book...so I guess it is a typo in the book. How would you explicitly write your answer in the Cartesian form as in my post?

Comment: And did you reproduce that plot in wolfram? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user9106985 $$y+3=\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right) x$$ it is even simpler in this form